# PHP 7.4 trimming whitespace between string variables

Tags: php, twig, timber

I'm running into an issue where when I have multiple variables being output into a class attribute, they all get compressed into a single word rather than kept as separate words as originally authored, as in

```
<div class="className {{ variable1 }} {{ variable2 }}"><div>
```

At runtime this is being rendered as:

```
<div class="className variable1variable2"><div>
```

Any idea what would cause this and how to avoid it?

Comment: This output is weird, since there is a space between the `{{}} {{}}`, it should work as expected. Try to use string concate instead, such as `{{ variable1 ~ ' ' ~ variable2 }}`

Comment: Does WordPress’s `the_content` filter run over this?

Comment: This runs outside the scope of `the_content`. Trying to pinpoint what triggers it as apparently it doesn't affect all sites running PHP 7.4 and Timber.

Comment: I don't think this is caused by PHP or Twig specifically - could you expand your question with more information about your environment? Ie, any framework, plugins, type of server etc. My guess is that there's a filter somewhere trying and failing to be helpful.

Comment: You may be onto something @Bananaapple, as I don't get consistent behaviour across all sites. Trying to pinpoint the specific set of circumstances that triggers this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faced the same issue on PHP 7.4. Found this [fix](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/3004/commits/1fb0f9701d8443083495cd2645e8a0c45d54c34d) on GitHub.

So if you're using Twig 1, upgrade it at least to **v1.43.0**.

If you're using Twig 2, upgrade it at least to **v2.10.0**. *(my case - I had v2.7.4 in the project).*

Comment: Anyone know what change in PHP 7.4 triggered this? The changelog for the fix seems highly unspecific.

Comment: Relevant solution for 1.2x and similar in case someone can't upgrade: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554618/5256092