# How to fix Html tag issue in Twig file after upgrade PHP version

Tags: php, twig

I have a WordPress theme based on twig templates. Now I upgrade PHP version 7.2 to 7.4.  After upgrading this version I am getting issues with the HTML tag. Space gets removed from the attribute.

```
<labelclass="in-label in-label"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Commercial" for="cf47rs_cf47rs-property-filter-8_property_type_0">Commercial
            </labelclass="in-label>
```

When I change the PHP version to old one then this issue gets fixed. How i can fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig problem with php 7.4 in write variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248533/twig-problem-with-php-7-4-in-write-variable)

Comment: No. Did not work

Comment: Well. What have you tried then? Did you update the twig version to start with?

Comment: No. I tried this solution: 'Find in file Lexer.php function lexData line 163 change:'

Comment: I am not sure about how I can update the twig version because all files are loading from a plugin with vendor folder.

Comment: Strange that updating `lexData` doesn't work. Worked instantly here. Did you clean your cache folder before trying? In order to update the twig version you should be able to update the composer file

Comment: So your function now looks like [this](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/3004/commits/1fb0f9701d8443083495cd2645e8a0c45d54c34d) right?

Answer (score 0):

Just update to the latest twig version, latest master versions have been fixed. See the [change on GitHub](http://%20https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/3004/commits/1fb0f9701d8443083495cd2645e8a0c45d54c34d).

I am using version 1 and the issue has gone after updating twig vendor with composer.

```
$ composer update twig/twig

Package operations: 1 install, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.23.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating twig/twig (v1.35.3 => v1.43.1): Loading from cache
```